# Qual ferramenta posso usar para criar um pacote de Instalador em Silent Mode?

Tags: instalador, setup

Tenho cerca de 10 programas que precisam ser instalados em uma certa ordem e com certos parametros.

Qual ferramenta (GRATUITA) eu poderia usar para desenvolver um único executável, que instale todos eles de uma vez em silent mode (de preferência) ??

Comment: Bloco de notas, você pode gerar um arquivo .bat que faça o que você precisa.

Comment: Procuro algum software que faça isso :/